# listening to the jasmineDone event

Tags: jasmine

I'm writing some integration tests for a webAPI with the help of jasmine.

What I want to accomplish is to hook into the jasmineDone event to cleanup some testdata that I've added  but I can´t seem to get my head around how to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you're trying and what you want to have happen? If you're totally lost, here's an example I fixed for someone else which might help as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/2uyz2qhu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is to create a testfile with just an empty test that does the cleanup. Just remember to put that as the last file in the html page. Ref:https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jasmine-js/DSSGh1XCLfY